# Today, again, for some reason I was logged out of Superuser and, Indeed Meta. I didn't log out! Why am I logged out?

Tags: support, status-completed, firefox, logout

Today, again, for some reason I was logged out of Superuser and, Indeed Meta. I didn't log out! Why am I logged out?

This has happened at least twice that I am aware of.

Regards,

Comment: It wasn't just you. Me thinks an update was rolled out, and to clear out any cached js et al a logout was done

Comment: It happened to me as well =) I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: Please don't create or use the SuperUser or SuperUsr tags. We know this is relevant to SuperUser, no need to tag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the blog [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)

Comment: Thank you. A complete answer.